# How to create Concentric Circles in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector

I'm trying to build a planning tool for [center pivot irrigation system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_pivot_irrigation).  It involves selecting a field (polygon), a center point, and then an outer circle to set the outer limits of the system.  From there you select the inner rings based on fixed length sections. to optimize the coverage area.  Anyone have an idea where I can start?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem, but from the description, I would convert your polygons to centroids and then you can buffer the centroid.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the buffer tool to build  a series of layers at each radius.  For the best results make sure your point data is in a projection that uses feet or meters as the unit of measure.

Answer (score 1):

You can create circles of specific size using the buffer tool.

Please expand on the rest of your question to clarify what exactly you need.